# Sort by or re-order, instead of hiding/showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to refactor my Javascript/Jquery to use a select option and hidden input value in order to sort the divs on the page.

Currently, my JS works but it's hiding all divs whose hidden input has a value of 0. I want to keep the logic, but instead of hiding, just reorder the divs.

So if the user selects `Recently_ordered` from the select box, then any div whose hidden input has a value of 1 would show first and all with 0 would show after. Basically, all items remain on page but reorder slightly.

here's the working script that currently hides:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#filterText').on('change', function() {
  var currentVal = $(this).val();

  $(".group-container").show();

  if (currentVal == 'recently_ordered') {
    $('.group-container input[name="reorder"]').each(function (index, value){

        if($(this).val() == "0"){
                $(this).parent('.group-container').hide();
            }
      });
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

And the basic structure of the HTML:

```
@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
<div class="group-container">
        <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="{{$pgroup->topseller}}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="{{$pgroup->reorder}}"/>
```

Comment: Grab the `.group-container` elements as array, sort it according to their reorder value and append them to the DOM in the order of the array.

Comment: sorry for any confusion, but I'm very new to JS so could you give me just a brief idea of how to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the `.group-container` elements as array, sort it according to their reorder value and append them to the DOM in the order of the array.

The snippet is really verbose but should give enough informations to follow the code.

The functions used in this snippet should all have a link to the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com) or the description in the [Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/) in the comments.

The "groups" in the DOM have the mentioned hidden input fields and an additional `<p>` element which shows the value of the `topseller` and `reorder` fields which should make it easier to follow the changes from the script.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#filterText").on("change", function() {
    var container = $(".container"),  // get the surrounding container, used for appending the sorted groups
        groups = $(".group-container").get(),  // grab the "groups" and make them a regular array
                                               // .get() -> https://api.jquery.com/get/
        currentVal = this.value;  // the value of the selected option
        
    groups
      // first we have to sort them in the "correct" order
      // Array.prototype.sort() -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
      .sort(function(left, right) {
        var topsellerValueLeft = parseInt(left.querySelector('input[name="topseller"]').value, 10),   // get the value of the topseller field and make it a number
            topsellerValueRight = parseInt(right.querySelector('input[name="topseller"]').value, 10), // get the value of the topseller field and make it a number
            // Element.prototype.querySelector -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector
            // parseInt() -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
            // parseInt($(left).find('input[name="topseller"]').val(), 10)
            // parseInt($(right).find('input[name="topseller"]').val(), 10)
            // would yield the same result, but we don't need two full-blown jQuery objects just to get the value
            reorderValueLeft,
            reorderValueRight;
            
        // in case of "recently ordered" we sort the groups on their reorder value
        if (currentVal === "recently_ordered") {
          reorderValueLeft = parseInt(left.querySelector('input[name="reorder"]').value, 10);    // get the value of the reorder field and make it a number
          reorderValueRight = parseInt(right.querySelector('input[name="reorder"]').value, 10);  // get the value of the reorder field and make it a number
          
          // we have to check the reorder value only when the values are different
          if (reorderValueLeft !== reorderValueRight) {
            return reorderValueRight - reorderValueLeft;  // sort descending -> 1 ... 0
          }
        }
        
        // either we are not supposed to sort the items by their reordered value
        // or they have the same reordered value
        // hence we will then sort them on their topseller value
        // this time in ascending order
        return topsellerValueLeft - topsellerValueRight;
      })
      // now we append the elements to the DOM in the same order as we find them in the array
      // this will "remove" the groups one by one from the DOM and append it at their correct new spot
      // Array.prototype.forEach() -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
      .forEach(function(group) {
        container.append(group);  // .append() -> https://api.jquery.com/append/
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filterText">
  <option value="default">default</option>
  <option value="recently_ordered">recently ordered</option>
</select>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="group-container">
    <p>1 | 1</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="group-container">
    <p>2 | 0</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="group-container">
    <p>3 | 1</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="group-container">
    <p>4 | 0</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="topseller" value="4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="reorder" value="0" />
  </div>
</div>
```

(or on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/cs8m3mwt/))

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work great. However, should there be both a 'groups' and a 'group' singular and plural?

Comment: Are you talking about the `groups` array and the `group` parameter in the `.forEach()`?

Comment: The singular `group` is just a name for the parameter. But because this will be an element of the `groups` array it just makes sense to use the singular for it - imho :)